# compare two set of string in php and echo the difference and word number

Tags: php

is there a function that compare word per word and count word
for example this maybe a thousand of words to two pharagraphs so if there will be a conflict please include what method to use

$paragraph1="the big brow fox jump over the lazy dog and got tripped";

$paragraph2="the big brown fox jump over the lazy dog and got trippe";

and echo the difference and the number of words

paragraph 1 brow

paragraph 2 brown

paragraph 1 tripped

paragraph 2 trippe

pharagraph 1 number of words:12

pharagraph 2 number of words:12

and display and highlight the different words

"the big **brow** fox jump over the lazy dog and got **tripped**"

"the big **brown** fox jump over the lazy dog and got **trippe**"

Comment: yes, the function *you* write can do this.

Comment: its like Compare It software

Answer (score 2):

I am trying to do something similar for one of my projects so you can try this code. You might need to tweak it a bit according to your needs. Also, there might be multiple ways to accomplish this:

```
$paragraph1="the big brow fox jump over the lazy dog and got tripped";

$paragraph2="the big brown fox jump over the lazy dog and got trippe";

$par1_arr = explode(' ', $paragraph1);
$par2_arr = explode(' ', $paragraph2);

var_dump(array_diff($par1_arr, $par2_arr));
```

This gives this output:

```
array(2) { [2]=> string(4) "brow" [11]=> string(7) "tripped" }
```